# how to allow fragmented packets through firewall (ipv4/v6)?

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables

is there a iptables rule that allows the fragmented ipv4/v6 packets?

i searched in the web it shows that the fragmented packets doesn't contain the port number so the firewall simply drops the packets, the top application will be waiting in select or read call and wont recieve any packets.

help needed.

Answer (score 1):

> I searched in the web it shows that the fragmented packets doesn't contain the port number

Don't believe everything you read on the Web. TCP pre-fragments its segments so they shouldn't get re-fragmented later on, and segment fragments do contain the port number.

Comment: thanks for the answer, how should i match the packet then ?
with ip or mac? if so my firewall becomes weak in the way that it accepts all packets on that ip or that mac.

Answer (score 1):

If you do any form of stateful / connection tracking the kernel will handle the fragments directly.

However, if you have a stateless router, you can add -f to match on fragmented packets.  This can be good for fragmented udp packets.  To allow all fragmented packets through a router and let the host deal with them:
iptables -A FORWARD -f -j ACCEPT